# How can I use preg_replace to trim everything around a specific value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm attempting to find a value X, which matches the pattern:

```
<span class="line-item-quantity-raw">X</span>
```

Once I've got the value, I want to trim everything else around it. While I know I could do this with preg_match just to get the value and set the variable, I'm quite curious as to why I can't get my original method with preg_match to function.

```
$footer = '<div class="line-item-summary">
  <div class="line-item-quantity">
    <span class="line-item-quantity-raw">1</span>
    <span class="line-item-quantity-label">item</span>
  </div>
  <div class="line-item-total">
    <span class="line-item-total-label">Total:</span>
    <span class="line-item-total-raw">$1,500.00</span>
  </div>
</div>';

$pattern = '/.*<span class="line-item-quantity-raw">(\d+)<\/span>.*/';
$replace = '($1) -';
$footer = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $footer);
```

Unfortunately this only seems to strip out the span tags as specified in the `$pattern` however the extra markup on the edges of the `$pattern` such as `.*` is still being kept.

Annoyingly running my code in a test page such as http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php seems to work, just not my code above in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `.` is not matching by default line breaks. To make `.` span multiple lines, you need to add the modifier `s`:

```
$pattern = '/.*<span class="line-item-quantity-raw">(\d+)<\/span>.*/s';
```

> **s** (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline character,  independent of the setting of this modifier.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: Just be aware that the `DOTALL` flag is a bit of a blunt instrument. Use of the non-greedy quantifiers `+?`, `*?` to avoid over-matching too much of the string is highly recommended anyway, but doubly so when using `DOTALL`.

Comment: @Li-aungYip your point is absolutely valid, but in this special case it's the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the dot does not match newlines.

If you use the `/s` modifier, then it will match them (and the entire rest of the string, which may or may not be what you want).

```
$pattern = '/.*<span class="line-item-quantity-raw">(\d+)<\/span>.*/s';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you have way too much rep though :)